# ¿Cómo desbloquear pestañas en Firefox para Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox

Entré hace pocos días como sysadmin jr en una empresa callcenter, en la cual se tienen las maquinas instaladas con Ubuntu 14.04, en las cuales el operador solo puede loguearse mediante una consola del gestor de entrada de Gnome. Luego al loguearse, deben iniciar un programa que se ejecuta sobre firefox y da acceso a la base de datos para que puedan trabajar. El firefox se encuentra blockeado para que no aparezca ninguna botonería ni barra de marcadores (algo similiar al apretar F11 en windows, para que pase a pantalla completa).

La situación es la siguiente: Me están solicitando habilitar las pestañas de Firefox, para que puedan abrir las páginas de Google Maps, ya que no se lo permiten sino. Esto se había realizado previamente, pero al cambiar los usuarios y sus legajos, perdieron la configuración.

Hay carpetas creadas como home de usuarios en /tmp/ en la cual poseen el nombre /tmp/xxxxhome/, y en el mismo nivel del /tmp/ hay mismas carpetas que poseen el numero de legajo, pero seguido de Orbit, que por lo que pude observar, se crea al loggearse un usuario en el sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar utilizando la funcion de new tab al usar el scroll button del mouse. Luego de eso reinicie el navegador a su estado de fabrica para tenerlo como una instalación limpia, y luego de eso, habiendo configurado todo lo necesario para los usuarios, copie todo el contenido de la carpeta **/tmp/$usr$/.firefox** a la carpeta **/etc/skel/.firefox** , para que proximos usuarios en loggearse, se les generara el perfil ya armado.